# RichTextBox to BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#

How can I throw `RichTextBox1`'s value to a `BackgroundWorker` in C#?

```
public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text.Trim())){
        MessageBox.Show("No value in RichTextBox?");
        return;
    }

    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
    {
        // Start the asynchronous operation.
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(richTextBox1);
    }
```

Here's my `BackgroundWorker`'s code:

```
public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    foreach (string vr in richTextBox1.Lines)
    {
    ⋮
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @agent-j 

`$exception {"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(richTextBox1.Text);

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (string)e.Argument;
        MessageBox.Show(text);

    }
```

The text is sent as object e.argument. To retrieve it cast e.argument back to a string (or string[] etc depending on what you pass)

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass the RichTextBox for reasons given above, but you can pass in the string array which is the RichTextBox.Lines Property and iterate through that.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bg.RunWorkerAsync(richTextBox1.Lines);
}

void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = (string[])e.Argument;
    foreach(string vr in lines)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually only the Main UI thread can interact with Forms and Controls.

Consider passing all the data it needs  to the `RunWorkerAsync` method -- perhaps `RunWorkerAsync(richTextBox1.Lines.ToList())`.

Comment: And how to extracting richTextBox1.Lines.ToList() in backgroundworker?